# How do I increase the Export quota on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We discovered today that there is a quota of 1000 exports per day from BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) (yes, it is published in the docs, but we are too busy to memorize every restriction by heart). Besides the obvious question (Why?!!), **how can we get someone on the phone to increase our quota today**, at least temporarily, so that we can keep doing business today without waiting another 24 hours?

Why the restriction in the first place? We are exporting data from one Google product that we pay (quite a lot) for (BigQuery) to another one that we are also paying for storage!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have support package? If so I believe you can call customer service and they will open bug for this.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/support